# How do I write test-only code in Production code using #ifdef in C++?

Tags: c++, testing, preprocessor, compiler-directives

NOTE: I think this is quite basic, please point me in the right direction if this is already answered. I did look online but surprisingly unable to find the answer, I could be using wrong words to search.

I felt I should be able to do by defining preprocessor directives in project properties but I believe I am missing something basic.

Here's what I would like to accomplish - say I have some code like the following that ships to production:

```
//In Foo.hpp
class Foo
{
   public:
      Foo()
      ~Foo()
      ...
}

//In Foo.cpp
Foo::Foo()
{
   #ifdef THIS_IS_TEST_MODE
      BarTest();
   #else
      Bar();
   #elseif
}
```

**Goal:** In Foo()'s constructor, I want BarTest() to run only when a Foo is instantiated in test code.

**Context:** I am using BOOST, so I am basically using BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE and BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_CASE macros in test code. There is a .props file that is currently included in all prod and test project files.

**What I have tried already:** Added another .props file with a preprocessor directive TEST and included this .props file only in test project. While #ifdef TEST evaluates to true in test project, it evaluates to false in the production code. I think this happens because the new .props config applies only to test project.

**Alternatives:** I guess I can add a parameter, say, `bool test` to Foo's ctor and default it to false so it is only true from test code. However, I feel that could lead to bugs in the future.

Comment: There is no universal rule or law about how to do this. Test suites are highly application-specific and each application will require a different, customized approach to write test-suites.

Comment: Thanks Sam :) May be what I am looking for is a way to define a directive that's applied globally but only when a test project is built.

Comment: If you want a macro to work like you describe, then it explicitly needs to be defined in the same way in every compilation unit when compiling.   You can't build your "test code" with `THIS_IS_TEST_MODE` defined, and your "production code" with `THIS_IS_TEST_MODE` undefined, and expect the two to behave consistently.    Macros are expanded in an early phase of compilation and defining `THIS_IS_TEST_MODE` in one compilation unit does not magically cause code in another compilation unit to be have as if it is defined.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I think what I actually need is the THIS_IS_TEST_MODE to be only defined when test project is built. I understand that when it is defined it will be so for both test and production code :)